# Uso de enum dentro de um Struct

Tags: c, enums

Boa noite. Tenho que fazer um programa em que tenho de criar vários elementos usando os seguinte enum e struct:

```
typedef enum {ATRIB, ADD, SUB, MUL, IF_I, PRINT, READ, GOTO_I, LABEL} OpKind;

typedef enum {EMPTY, INT_CONST, STRING} ElemKind;

typedef struct{
     ElemKind kind;
      union{ 
        int val;
        char *name;
        } contents;
} Elem;

typedef struct{
   OpKind op;
   Elem first, second, third;
} Instr;
```

No entanto não estou a conseguir perceber como atribuir valores a cada um dos elementos de `Instr`.
Alguém consegue dar algum exemplo simples de como posso fazer a atribuição?
Obrigado

Comment: Algo do tipo:
Instr.first.kind = EMPTY;

Comment: Obrigado já ficou mais claro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Instr` é um **tipo**. Tens de definir um *objecto* (uma variável) desse tipo para lhe atribuires um valor.

```
Instr foo; // foo não inicializado
Instr bar = {0}; // bar inicializado com zeros
Instr baz = {ATTRIB, {EMPTY, {0}}, {INT_CONST, {42}}, {STRING, {-1}}};
Instr quux = { .op = READ }; // C99 designated initializer

foo.second.contents.name = "foo"; // atribuição
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pelos exemplos já ficou mais claro como atribuir valores